# Core Data Dynamic Managed Object Model

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I already have created a dynamic managed object model, but this can be used only when the application is running. 
How can i save programmatically this dynamic model to a .momd file like Xcode does when a .xcdatamodeld is present in the project in order to persist the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSManagedObjectModel` conforms to `NSCoding`. So `-encodeWithCoder:` should work.

Did you try it?